# MainWindow-iPad.xib in xcode 4.6.3

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Now I am reading the book Head First iPhone and iPad Development 2nd edition(Dan Pilone, Tracey Pilone). And when, according to the exercise in the book , I need to change the program from iphone to universal in the book xcode is making MainWindow-iPad.xib automatically, but my xcode doesn't. Also from the beginning program in book has file MainWindow.xib, but I don't. What should I do now?  If I will change MasterViewController.xib (Navigation template) the changes will also be in iPhone simulator version.

Answer (score 1):

Rephrasing your question as per your comment:

> If smb want to make an universal program and xibs need to be different on ipad and on iPhone, what to do?

You do this in your appDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[HWViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HWViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[HWViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HWViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

That code is taken straight from the Single View Template in XCode - but the code is valid with or without a template.

It assumes you have two separate xib files, one called "HWViewController_iPhone.xib" and the other called "HWViewController_iPad.xib". The names don't matter so long as they agree with the `initWithNibName:` string in the code (you leave out the '.xib' in the code).

You can make the xib files in XCode with New > File > User Interface > View

Comment: Now I have this code in Appdelegate.m

Answer (score 0):

Your book is out of date.  You can do it that route by using adding a xib and setting it as the Main Interface in deployment info in Target Summary.

Really though there's very little reason to do this.  The better way is to create a root view controller and set it up in your app delegate.

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I have this code in Appdelegate.m :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HWViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HWViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

And 3 errors: Property 'viewController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *' 
after this strings:

```
self.viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HWViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
self.viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HWViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```